# Butterknife bind SearchView from Menu

Tags: android, butterknife

In my current Android project I use the `Butterknife` library to bind views and use `onClick` annotations for them. This all works great even in fragments but now I'm at the point where I can't find a solution:

I use the new `ToolBar` as `ActionBar` and inflate a Menu with a `SearchView` in it. For this `SearchView` I want to use the `@OnTextChanged` annotation but when I call the bind method with the `ActionView` of the menu item `Butterknife` tries to reinstanciate all Views again and of course in the `ActionView` it can not find any other Views of the `RootLayout`.

So is there a way to add only one `View` with `Butterknife` or can I get a View which contains all Views from my `RootLayout` and the `ToolBarView` so I can pass this View to the bind method? For example in Activites I can call `findViewById` also for menu IDs but if I use `getView()` from my Fragment it does not work. Any ideas for this?

Comment: A feature was requested to make this happen, but it was rejected by Jake Wharton. Please see issue [#41](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/41) and [#416](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/416) and said **I want to keep this focused on assisting with view-realted things only.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is not possible since the SearchView is a menu item. The id you are using in the menu declaration identifies this view within the menu, *not the activity's view*, thats probably why Butterknife is no able to bind it.

I'm afraid you will have to do:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.bookings_list_menu, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(...);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(...);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(...);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```